# How do I exit a community?

Tags: support, profile-page

I genuinely can't find out how to remove some of the Stack Exchange sites that I no longer use from my profile.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact

Comment: Sorry - are you asking how to delete your account on a specific site - or hide that you're a member on a specific site from your profile?

Comment: @jon delete my account on multiple specific sites, not simply hide them